# Keep digits in Mallet topic modeling

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, mallet

I am using Mallet for topic modeling. A large amount of words in my input text include both letters and digits; e.g., A54, D892. I just noticed that Mallet automatically removes the digits and only keeps the letters in the words. I even do not use the --remove-stopwords option when importing my text file. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`bin/mallet import-dir` has an option `--token-regex` which determines what to accept as part of the word. One of the following two choices may suit your needs: `[\p{L}\p{D}]+` accepts any combinations of letters and digits; `\p{L}[\p{L}\p{D}]*` accepts alphanumerical strings starting with a letter.